# Update WooCommerce "flat rate" shipping cost using jQuery

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to update the shipping cost after the address is entered. When the client starts typing the address, and autocomplete function helps the client find the street name, building, floor, and side.

Once the address is entered JavaScript calculates the distance and the price.

Then the price is via AJAX send to `shipment.php`

It is my goal to have shipment update the shipping cost accordingly.

I have tried:

```
include '../../../../wp-load.php';

add_action( 'woocommerce_flat_rate_shipping_add_rate','add_another_custom_flat_rate', 10, 2 );
function add_another_custom_flat_rate( $method, $rate ) {
       $new_rate = $rate;
       $new_rate['cost'] = 50; // Update the cost to 50
       $method->add_rate( $new_rate );
     }
```

But without luck.

I have also following this guide and added another shipping method: Tuts
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-for-woocommerce--cms-26098

But once again, I cannot update the price once the address is entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think that **You don't need** Query ajax to update the price **directly** for this calculated shipping cost and **you don't need** a custom shipping method as in your code or linked tutorial.

**THERE IS THREE STEPS:**

1) In your existing Ajax driven PHP function, you will set the calculated price in a custom WC_Session attribute where `$shipping_cost` variable will be the collected value of the calculated shipping cost passed via JS Ajax:

```
WC()->session->set( 'shipping_calculated_cost', $shipping_cost );
```

Then in **jQuery** Ajax "on success" event you will update checkout with the following:

```
$('body').trigger('update_checkout');
```

That will refresh checkout data…

---

2) In the custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_package_rates`** filer hook, you will get the session value of the calculated shipping cost…

> IMPORTANT: In WooCommerce settings > shipping, you will **set** the **"flat rate" cost to `1`**…

In The function code you will set the default price for this flat rate (that will be used when the shipping cost calculation doesn't exist yet):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'update_shipping_costs_based_on_cart_session_custom_data', 10, 2);
function update_shipping_costs_based_on_cart_session_custom_data( $rates, $package ){

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return $rates;

    // SET HERE the default cost (when "calculated cost" is not yet defined)
    $cost = '50';

    // Get Shipping rate calculated cost (if it exists)
    $calculated_cost = WC()->session->get( 'shipping_calculated_cost');

    // Iterating though Shipping Methods
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate_values ) {
        $method_id = $rate_values->method_id;
        $rate_id = $rate_values->id;

        // For "Flat rate" Shipping" Method only
        if ( 'flat_rate' === $method_id ) {
            if( ! empty( $calculated_cost ) ) {
                $cost = $calculated_cost;
            }
            // Set the rate cost
            $rates[$rate_id]->cost = number_format($rates[$rate_id]->cost * $cost, 2);
            // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            foreach ($rates[$rate_id]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$key] > 0 ){ // set the new tax cost
                    $taxes[$key] = number_format( $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$key] * $cost, 2 );
                    $has_taxes = true;
                } else {
                    $has_taxes = false;
                }
            }
            if( $has_taxes )
                $rates[$rate_id]->taxes = $taxes;
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme) or in any plugin file.

---

**3) Refresh the shipping caches *(needed sometimes)*:**

> - First empty your cart.
> - This code is already saved on your function.php file.
> - Go in a shipping zone settings and disable one "flat rate" *(for example)* and "save". Then re-enable that "flat rate" and "save". **You are done and you can test it.**

This should work for you,

> If you have many **different "flat rates" by shipping zones**, you will need to make some changes in my code, if the default cost is different for each…

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have followed you three steps exactly. 

I can see that the WC()->session->set( 'shipping_calculated_cost', $_POST['shipping_costs'] ) is set correctly. I can see WooCommerce is updating the cart (it gets sort of flashes). However the price for the flat rate remains 1. Is there something I am missing? Best regards.

Comment: @user1576298 that is not normal because if the "shipping_calculated_cost" doesn't come in my code, it's replaced by the default price that you have set in it (so not 1). try again to disable/save enable/save the flat rate in shipping methods… unlog… empty browser cache… delete the related coockies domain.name… and try again please

Comment: I have now tried empty browser cache, disabled/save + enable/save the flat rate. But still without luck.

I am wondering: Don't I have to set the variable: $rates ?

Comment: IT WORKS! The code had a small small error.

 foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        $method_id = $rate_values->method_id;
        $rate_id = $rate_values->id;
.....

Had to be
 foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        $method_id = $rate->method_id;
        $rate_id = $rate->id;
        // For "Flat rate" Shipping" Method


But OMG!!! THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH!! If you ever stop by Denmark I'll buy you a beer or a soda

Comment: @SorenPeter Yes of course, you are right! I didn't pay attention to this when I have renamed some variables… I have updated my answer… I was pretty sure that it will work for your case. I take the plane to Denmark now, prepare the beers :)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec In my code works only with additional  
        WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();

Comment: @HorheGarcia This code is tested and works as it is… If for you it works with an additional `WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();` it's just fine and good. If it was useful and you like/want you can upvote this answer.